# Laravel query, foreach function to remove items then paginate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

A user searches profiles within a certain km radius i.e. 50 km of which I run function which uses latitude/longitude values to retrieve results (this is a rough search within a square not straight line distance), I then paginate the results.

`$query = $this->filterNearby($query, $geocode);
$query = $query->paginate(10);`

But for each query I need to run a proper distance using great circle formula (to get accurate 50km) AND the people searched may only willing to travel 20km from their location so I need to remove these from the query.

I have tried to do a `$query = $query->get()` prior to pagination, then do a for each to remove items but then the pagination does not work. I have tried to create a new Paginator but am unsure how this works through to the view?

Latest code:

```
if (\Request::segment(2) == "jobs")
            {                   
                $query = $this->searchJob($search_strategy);
                $query = $this->filterNearbyJob($query, $geocode);
                $query = $this->filterJob($query);

                $query = $query->get();

                // Foreach function to go here to get accurate distance between two points and remove from query results

                $paginate = new Paginator($query, count($query), 10);  

                $category = $this->getCategoryURL($search_strategy);                
                $sub_categories = ServiceSubCategory::where('sub_category_url', '=', $search_strategy)->first();

                return view('search.job')
                    ->with('category', $category)
                    ->with('sub_categories', $sub_categories)
                    ->with('search_results', $paginate);    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `get` prior to `paginate`, as a matter of fact, you can only call one of them. You should filter with the database query or consider making an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` or `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`

Comment: Hi Javier, thank you - had attempted that, shown code above but it sending all results to the view is it possible to me know where I'm heading wrong here. I think this lies with how to get the new pagination through to the view.